# Variable scope php inside class and function

Tags: php, function

The issue I am having is that I can't seem to use dynamic variables inside a class and function.

I would like to load `$p_name` which gets its value from `$p_real_name` (a database entry) but this doesn't work, even though the first two examples in the code works just fine.

Am I missing something simple? I tried to concatenate a few different ways, but really, I feel like I'm out my depth..

```
    $p_real_name = $row['input_1']; //This comes further up the code
    $p_name = 1; // Works fine
    $p_name = test; // Works fine
    $p_name = $p_real_name; // Does not work. 
    //If I echo out $p_real_name or even $p_name here, I get the correct value back.
    class myFunctionClass{
        private $_api_user;
        private $_api_key;
        private $_token;
        private $_test; 

        public function __construct($api_user, $api_key, $p_name){
            $this->_api_user = $api_user;
            $this->_api_key = $api_key;
            $this->_test = $p_name; 
            }
        public function login(){
            $result = $this->_make_api_call('users/login', true, array('api_user' => $this->_api_user, 'api_key' => $this->_api_key));
            $this->_token = $result['token'];
        }
        public function getToken(){
            return $this->_token;
        }
        public function myFunction($p_name) {
            $this->_test = $p_name; //tried with or without global
                $params = array(
                    'token'                 => $this->_token,
                    'receiver_name'         => $this->_test, //this only works with the first 2 examples of $p_name at the top of the code, not the 3rd example
                    'receiver_address1'     => $p_address
                );
    $ch = curl_init();      //Latest edit
    $query = http_build_query($params);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::API_ENDPOINT . '/' . 'shipments/imported_shipment');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $output = curl_exec ($ch);
            $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close ($ch);

            $output = json_decode($output, true);
        }
    }
    $testObject = new myFunctionClass($api_user, $api_key, $p_name);
    $testObject->login();
    $testObject->getToken();
    $testObject->myFunction($p_name);
```

The problem is 'receiver_name' does not get correct data input if I use  `$p_name = $p_real_name;` only when I use `$p_name = 1; or $p_name = static;`

Comment: So what isn't working here, its hard to tell from you question.

Comment: First of all, do not use global. Never. Ever. There is no single reason to use it. When you think there is no other option than to use global it means you just have to think longer :)

Comment: @Jeff, I tried adding a few lines below the updated code - hope that clarifies?

Comment: @awons I tried both with and without using global, seems to work fine with the static values either way, so I've removed it from the code above.

Comment: Your function `myFunction()` doesn't really do anything. `return` or `var_dump()` something.

Comment: @IkoTikashi I updated the topic to include the what happens in `myFunction()`

Comment: Nothing wrong with that class/method, tested it locally and sets `$this->_test` correctly, your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the way if fetching the data from `$row['input_1'];` ? Do you have any other idea as to what sort of problem it could then be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class constructor is defined as this

```
public function __construct($api_user, $api_key, $p_name)
```

and you are calling it like this

```
$testObject = new myFunctionClass($api_user, $api_key);
```

PHP should give you an error on that because you are only passing two variables instead of three.
Do the right thing first then we know what exactly isn't working and why.

It should look like this

```
 $testObject = new myFunctionClass($api_user, $api_key, $p_name);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add $p_name as you suggested, still won't get it to output into the array.

Comment: @Mark you don't need to pass $p_name as an argument to myFunction() anymore, that it's value is in $this->_test